# Kubernetes - Deployment/replicaSet

Tags: kubernetes, deployment

I am learning concepts in kubernetes, when i am going through deployments and replicaset concepts i got one doubt that `can replicasets and deployment be independent to each other`

Comment: The replicas of a deployment are managed by the replication controller through the replica set. One can, however, have replica sets without deployments.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* create a `ReplicaSet` without creating a `Deployment`, but nowadays it does not make much sense. You will almost always use only `Deployment` for deploying an application, and for every change, e.g. updating the `image:`, it will manage the creation of a new `ReplicaSet` for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can create `ReplicaSet` and `ReplicationController` also `Deployment` however nowadays all use `Deployment` which auto-create and manage `ReplicaSet`.

We can say Replicasset is updated version of the replication controller to understand easily.

You can deploy the same application using `Replicaset` & `Deployment`, however, with deployment it's easy to manage and update docker image.